# How to transfer IRfcTable details to SQL Server table?

Tags: .net, sql-server, saprfc

I am using an IRfcFunction in order to get certain values from SAP to my .net application. 
These details are in a IRfcTable structure.
I would like to know how to move these contents that are in the IRfcTable to SQL Server table.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate on rows returned in IRfcTable table, get the values of each row and insert it manually into your SQL Server table.

```
for (var i = 0; i < rfcTable.RowCount; ++i)
{
    var fieldValue = rfcTable[i].GetString("FIELD_NAME");
    // get other fields values
    // inert into SQL Server table according to your application logic
}
```